# Android android-layout xml warn

Tags: android, android-layout

How to handle the following warnings correctly

The item's text contrast ratio is 3.88. This ratio is based on an estimated foreground color of #73500B and an estimated background color of #FBAE17. Consider increasing this item's text contrast ratio to 4.50 or greater.

```
    The item's text contrast ratio is 3.88. This ratio is based on an estimated foreground color 

of #73500B and an estimated background color of #FBAE17. Consider increasing this item's text 

contrast ratio to 4.50 or greater.  Learn more at 

https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158390


    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/main_fr_rv"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:text="RecyclerView">

</TextView>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WOEC.png)

Comment: So did you learn more at the [link the error provides](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158390)?

Comment: Just click on the fix

Comment: Only know that the contrast ratio should reach 3.0, according to the w3c standard